Measurement and comparison of logical observable parity with stabilizer parity in stim
I've begun going throught stim, and part of the getting started notebook is confusing me.
The first issue I am having is w.r.t the logical observable. In the notebook, it refers to the leftmost qubit being the logical qubit, so of course this will be the top qubit in the circuit diagram. But looking at the output diagram of a distance 3 repetition code  it specifies, via OBS_INCLUDE(0) that the measurement that occurs on the last qubit, ie the rightmost one, is the logical observable. It even states that its rec[4], so it is the measurement of the rightmost data qubit. Not the leftmost one. Additionally, I fail to see how measuring one qubit would give you any information regarding the logical observable, which is a 3 qubit measurement, the parity of which is also the product of 3 qubits. What am I missing here?
On the topic of the parity, I am also confused about the DETECTORS at the end. I understand that they compare the measurement outcomes of the 2 stabilizers with the individual measurment outcomes of the observables that construct them, ie $Z_{1}Z_{2}$ is compared with $Z_{1}$ and $Z_{2}$, and given that no further errors have occurred on those qubits, then the measurement outcomes should agree with the syndrome, though obviously the measurement outcome will be non-deterministic.
But what is actually being done here? When I saw this, I can't recall having seen a check like this being performed in either the circuit examples in Chuang or in Surface Code examples like Surface codes: Towards practical large-scale quantum computation. Is there a specific name for this? I mean this is the measurement of the logical observable, ie either the logical $X$ or logical $Z$, depending on the type of repetition code. It's $ZZZ$ in this case I believe. But is this meant to be a circuit construction for fault tolerant measurements? Most of the examples I've seen are w.r.t fault tolerant measurements of a logical operator, ie what we do for syndrome measurements. Not for logical measurements. Moreover, give we also have errors on the syndrome qubits as well, and the small number of components, this can't be a fault tolerant construction.

In the repetition code, the stabilizers are $Z_1Z_2$ and $Z_2Z_3$. Hence, $Z_1Z_2Z_3$ and $Z_1$ represent the same logical $Z$ operator, up to multiplication by a stabilizer. This is true also for $Z_2$ and $Z_3$, so considering any single data qubit for the observable is perfectly fine. You could also have chosen equivalently the product of the three measurements rec[2]*rec[3]*rec[4].
Note that the label indicates L0 *= rec[4], meaning that in principle, the observable 0 (name unrelated to the qubit $q_0$) is rec[4] times some other measurements previously added through other OBS_INCLUDE(0) rec[...]. Since the qubit start in state $|0\rangle$, the logical qubit is $|0\rangle_L$ at the beginning so here another OBS_INCLUDE(0) rec[...] at the beginning is superfluous, but would be required if you were to start with $|1\rangle$s.
The problem with not doing the last step is that the first two measurements are faulty (they introduce an $X$ error at a rate of 1%). As I have explained in another answer about the surface code, you cannot end with potential measurement errors for the stabilizers in the last round due to how the decoding process works in general (a measurement error meaning here an $X$ error on an ancilla qubit that does not spread to the data qubits).
If you end the computation with an unknown measurement error for one stabilizer, error correction will not work anymore. Indeed, let's say only rec[1] was flipped. Looking at the syndrome, you will decide to apply an $X$ correction to the last qubit. Since your observable is $Z_3$ in this circuit, this means changing the observed logical state despite no $X$ error occurred on the data qubits (so it is a logical error) while at most 1 error occurred overall. Your code distance went from 3 to 1.
To circumvent this, a decoder will match error defects (ie triggered detectors) by pairs. When a measurement error happens, the two defects are paired between two different rounds (when you do multiple rounds of measurement) because measurement errors rarely happen twice in a row so the detector associated to that stabilizer is often flipped twice in a row.
If it happened on the last round of measurement (and you do not implement the last step), you wouldn't be able to pair it, because there is no upcoming round with the second detector flip.
When you measure directly the data qubits and reconstruct the stabilizer measurement outcomes as it is done here in the last step, a faulty measurement of one qubit corresponds exactly to an $X$ error on that qubit, so it will have a repercussion on two neighboring stabilizers. The reconstructed value of the stabilizer can be used to deduce if a measurement error happened on the previous step too.
I do not recall Nielsen and Chuang mentionning decoding algorithm, so this technicality might be absent. It is not really inherent to how stabilizer codes work, but to how you estimate their resilience to circuit noise.
In the repetition code particularly, you can avoid this problem by doing what you would do in the classical setup i.e. measure all the qubits and do a majority vote. This is specific to the repetition code and is not suitable for the more general stabilizer code framework targeted by stim.
Regarding the discrepancy between the observable being rec[4] and not rec[2], my guess is that under the hood (in the Python code), rec is used with negative (and relative to the end) indices (it is a Python list after all) because it is far more convenient. The Python code for this example probably end with rec[-1] which is changed in its visual representation to absolute indices rec[4]. rec[-1] comes before than the totally equivalent rec[-3] or rec[2] to the mind when you have been working with stim for a while

So in stim, it will take DETECTORS on qubits that are equivalent to the logical operation, ie the parity of measuring either those qubits, or all the logical qubits, would match, by default, instead of just the logical qubits of the operator?

Ah so this is why I was confused, those parity checks at the end aren't for surface code or general error detection/ correction. They are for decoder to determine if the syndrome qubits contained any errors themselves before they were measured, or the data qubits did after their syndrome was measured, so that the decoder can account for this when determing errors for correction. Is that correct?

So from that last paragraph, as you saying that when stim places rec[4] for the observable, it actually meant to place rec[2] instead? Does that mean that it doesn't matter which qubit that detector is placed on, only the measurement that is associated with said detector?

Using rec[4] means choosing $Z_3$ as an observable (the rightmost), rec[2] means chossing $Z_1$ (the leftmost). Both are equivalent but rec[2] would be better to be coherent with the notebook. When writing a stim circuit, you do not put detectors and obs_include on specific qubits, you just specify the measurement that they care about (you can add optionnal coordinates to detectors, but it only matters for 2D/3D visualization of the circuit, and you need to label the observables, but that's all). The circuit drawer here probably just places them on the involved qubit with the smallest label.
